# JavaFX ListView Resize behaviour

Tags: java, javafx

I am having a `ListView` in which i am adding a list of `HyperLink`,

Below is **MCVE**,

```
public class TestListView extends Application {

private int counter = 0;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    listView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(item);
                setGraphic(link);
                setText(item);
            }
        }
    });
    stage.setScene(new Scene(listView));
    stage.show();

    Timeline fiveSecondsWonder = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), (ActionEvent event) -> {
        listView.getItems().add("Link " + counter++);
    }));
    fiveSecondsWonder.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    fiveSecondsWonder.play();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

There is no problem adding the links in `ListView` but when i resize (continuously) the `ListView` in vertical direction (manually - using mouse), the row entries are duplicated.

How can i fix this behavior?

Comment: unrelated: don't recreate the hyperlink control in every call to updateItem (that's called ... often :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the listCell is empty you are setting only the text. Set the graphic also to null. Otherwise, the when the cells are reused, the graphic part of the labeled is still shown till it is overwritten.